# HTTP request in Async Task is blocking the UI

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm making an HTTP request to download a file.  This request for the data as well as writing the data to disk is done within an `AsyncTask`.  However, randomly when downloading the file the application will freeze for 5-10 seconds while the next block of data is read using `inputStream.read()`.  Since this is in an `AsyncTask`, the application should not freeze, correct?

The following is the code to start the `AsyncTask` (pseudocode):

```
MyClass {

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        (...)
        DownloadMedia dm = new DownloadMedia();
        dm.startDownload();
    }
}
```

And the code that does the downloading:

```
public class DownloadMedia {
    public void startDownload() {
        DownloadMediaTask task = new DownloadMediaTask();
        task.execute();
    }

    private class DownloadMediaTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        (...)

        URL url = new URL(file.getUrl());                  
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 50];
        int bufferLength = 0;
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {

            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

        }

        fileOutput.close();

        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller buffer size? Like maybe 1 KB instead of 50 KB?

Comment: Yes, I've lowered it to 1024 but the same thing happens.

Comment: Like you said this shouldn't freeze the UI. Have you confirmed that it is freezing only when the file is downloading? Can you post what leads you to think the AsyncTask is blocking the UI? If you spawn off too many of these tasks simultaneously I would expect a freeze. What does the code look like that calls the startDownload? Does it wait anyplace to finish?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed it is freezing only when the file is downloading.  I have put log statements in my code to determine exactly where it is stopping.  I am only spawning one thread so it isnt an issue with multiple threads.  I've updated my code in the original question to show where it is being called from. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you point `fileOutput`? To SD card? Can you try pointing it to internal storage and see if it solves the freezes?

Comment: It looks like that fixed the issue!  However, I have to write the file to the SD card.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, has this been resolved? Thank you so much.